# Rename files within a folder chronologically by name

Tags: .net, file-rename

I got a little program that renames files within a folder.
At this point it's almost working; the only problem that remains is that I want the program to rename the files alphabetically by name. This is my script now:

```
If TextBox4.Text = "" Or txtbSti.Text = "" Or ComboBox3.Text = "" Then
    MsgBox("Du må velge målmappe og Oppdatere Ønsket Output!", MsgBoxStyle.OkOnly, "Ooooops!")

Else
    Dim AntallFiler = My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(txtbSti.Text)
    Dim antall As Integer = CStr(AntallFiler.Count)
    Dim dir = txtbSti.Text
    Dim type = TextBox4.Text


    Dim sourcePath As String = dir
    Dim searchPattern As String = "*." & ComboBox3.Text
    Dim i As Integer = 1
    For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        File.Move(Path.Combine(sourcePath, fileName), Path.Combine(sourcePath, type & i & "." & ComboBox3.Text))
        i += 1
    Next


End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"chronologically by the name" doesn't make sense ... I'm assuming you mean sorted by name.

If so, try this:

```
        Dim list as New List(of string)
        list.AddRange(Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        list.Sort();
```

Then enumerate the list.

```
        For Each fileName As String In List
        Next
```

Comment: sorted by name is correct, apologize my bad english. But isn't there a way to sort it by name within this line "For Each fileName As String In Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath, searchPattern, SearchOption.AllDirectories)" ? Want it to be as simple as possible.

Comment: No not really ... arrays do not have sort and the list sort is an in place method

Comment: Got it to work with your method, thank you a bunch :) have a great day :)!